# Why json.RawMessage enlarge mongoDb document size?

Tags: mongodb, go, bson

The following codes try to insert new documents into mongoDB through `go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver`

```golang
    data := "this is test string blablablablablablabla"
    type Doc struct {
        Version int "json:version, bson:version"
        Data   string   "json:data, bson:data"
    }
    dd := Doc{Version: 21, Data: data}
    dObj, _ := json.Marshal(dd)

    queryFilter := bson.M{"version": 1}
    update1 := bson.M{"$set": bson.M{"version": 1, "data": json.RawMessage(dObj)}}

    // insert data with json.RawMessage
    _, err := db.Mongo("test").Collection("test_doc1").UpdateOne(context.Background(), queryFilter, update1, options.Update().SetUpsert(true))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("failed to insert doc1")
    }

    update2 := bson.M{"$set": bson.M{"version": 1, "data": (dObj)}}

    // insert data without json.RawMessage
    _, err = db.Mongo("test").Collection("test_doc2").UpdateOne(context.Background(), queryFilter, update2, options.Update().SetUpsert(true))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("failed to insert doc2")
    }
```

The content of `test_doc1` is `"data": json.RawMessage(dObj)`, whereas the  content of `test_doc2` is `"data": (dObj)`.

The document content as below

```
db.test_doc1.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5da164a950d625a5b2e5d23e"), "version" : 1, "data" : [ 123, 34, 86, 101, 114, 115, 105, 111, 110, 34, 58, 50, 49, 44, 34, 68, 97, 116, 97, 34, 58, 34, 116, 104, 105, 115, 32, 105, 115, 32, 116, 101, 115, 116, 32, 115, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 32, 98, 108, 97, 98, 108, 97, 98, 108, 97, 98, 108, 97, 98, 108, 97, 98, 108, 97, 98, 108, 97, 34, 125 ] }

db.test_doc2.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5da164a950d625a5b2e5d249"), "version" : 1, "data" : BinData(0,"eyJWZXJzaW9uIjoyMSwiRGF0YSI6InRoaXMgaXMgdGVzdCBzdHJpbmcgYmxhYmxhYmxhYmxhYmxhYmxhYmxhIn0=") }
```

After check the size of the above two documents

```
Object.bsonsize(db.test_doc2.findOne())
111

Object.bsonsize(db.test_doc1.findOne())
556
```

The size of `test_doc1` is more larger than `test_doc2`. Why?

Per [bson doc](http://bsonspec.org/spec.html)

> Array - The document for an array is a normal BSON document with integer values for the keys, starting with 0 and continuing sequentially. For example, the array ['red', 'blue'] would be encoded as the document {'0': 'red', '1': 'blue'}. The keys must be in ascending numerical order.

Bson array could occupy more disk space? Am I right?

MongoDB version: 4.0

Comment: The documents are clearly different. As noted One form is an **"array of integers"** at 32-bit's a piece ( even if the actual numeric values are all less than 255 ). The other form is just the full binary data. So just **plain bytes**. Of course one is much smaller than the other. Not an "apples to apples" comparison.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

test_doc1 uses `json.RawMessage` which is essentially `[]byte` so it gets stored as an array of integers which represent the string (raw representation of the document).

test_doc2 is storing the data as binary data which is a more compact form.

The Go Mongo Driver uses the `WriteBinaryWithSubtype` method for the json encoded data but uses `WriteArray` for the `RawMessage`.

The difference is in the data type being used on the mongo side to store these data. One is storing the byte slice as an array of integers, another is storing data as binary with a sub type. The binary form takes less space compared to the integers.

Digging deeper, I noticed the Go driver uses a registry to determine how it should encode a value to BSON. There's a method dedicated to byte slices.

```
// ByteSliceEncodeValue is the ValueEncoderFunc for []byte.
func (dve DefaultValueEncoders) ByteSliceEncodeValue(ec EncodeContext, vw bsonrw.ValueWriter, val reflect.Value) error {
```

This method uses the `WriteBinary()` method to encode byte slices as binary data.

Where as, if there's a custom type (even if it's a `[]byte` underneath), it would be treated as a slice type and trigger the "default encoder" for slices.

```
// SliceEncodeValue is the ValueEncoderFunc for slice types.
func (dve DefaultValueEncoders) SliceEncodeValue(ec EncodeContext, vw bsonrw.ValueWriter, val reflect.Value) error {
```

This method uses the `WriteArray()` method in turn.

**Summary:** The `json.Marshal` call gets use `[]byte` types directly so they are treated as bson binary type and stored in the compact binary form. `json.RawMessage` even though stores the data as `[]byte` internally is treated as a slice, a slice of integers and thus stored in mongo as an array of integers.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question though. The OP is asking why saving the same data in two different formats causes the document size to  increase by like 5 times

Comment: because the format is different? one is being stored as an array of integer, another one in binary form.

Comment: Let me try and rephrase this in a better way.

Comment: @AyushGupta Completely disagree with you and I suggest you try to understand what the answer actually says. As an "array of bye values" but expressed as **integers**, this actually stores in MongoDB as that many **integers** which are [**4-byte values***](http://bsonspec.org/spec.html) and **NOT ONE**. So the subsequent BSON size difference is indeed more that **4 times** the size, plus the additional padding on each integer value and the definition of the BSON Array. A BSON Binary field is just storing the data **as is**.

Comment: I have added more explanations, hope the answer is better now.